# Eventos multiples en JavaScript - addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo la siguiente duda en cuanto a eventos en JS, quiero manejar eventos múltiples, los cuales son "mouseover" "mouseout" & "click", cada vez que el puntero del ratón pasa por el elemento  con la clase llamada "navegadores" quiero que tenga ciertos comportamientos, intenté lo siguiente usando if pero no he tenido éxito con esa forma.

```
/************************************************************
   EVENTOS MULTIPLES
************************************************************/
```

/*
Creamos la variable "haz_algo" la cual contiene un querySelector
después le agregamos un evento escucha con ciertas acciones, eventos
de movimiento al ratón y uno de click
*/

```
let haz_algo=document.querySelector('.navegadores');
haz_algo.addEventListener('mouseover',metodo_1);
haz_algo.addEventListener('mouseout',metodo_2);
haz_algo.addEventListener('click',metodo_3);
```

/*
Preguntamos si la variable haz_algo contiene evento de escucha con
cierto valor para después agregarle propiedades de CSS, como
color de fondo y color de letra.
*/

```
if(type(haz_algo).addEventListener=='mouseover'){
   let metodo_1=function(){
      haz_algo.style.backgroundColor='green';
      haz_algo.style.color='white';
   }
}else{
    if(type(haz_algo).addEventListener=='mouseout'){
       let metodo_2=function(){
          haz_algo.style.backgroundColor='black';
          haz_algo.style.color='yellow';
    }
}else{
    if(type(haz_algo).addEventListener=='click'){
        let metodo_3=function(){
        haz_algo.style.backgroundColor='pink';
        haz_algo.style.color='black';
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Para poder solucionar lo que deseo intente lo siguiente, tres métodos por separado con ciertas acciones, de esta manera he podido conseguir lo que deseo, pero quiero saber ***¿Cómo puedo realizar estas mismas acciones teniendo if enlazado?***

```
let evento=document.querySelector('.navegadores');
evento.addEventListener('mouseover',metodo_1);
evento.addEventListener('mouseout',metodo_2);
evento.addEventListener('click',metodo_3);

function metodo_1(){
   evento.style.backgroundColor='red';
   evento.style.color='white';
}

function metodo_2(){
   evento.style.backgroundColor='black';
   evento.style.color='yellow';
}

function metodo_3(){
   evento.style.backgroundColor='pink'
   evento.style.color='black';
}
```

Comparto la estructura de HTML que he usado para este fin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Evento JS</title>
</head> 

<body>
   <div>
       <div class="navegadores">
           <p class="text">Una Imagen</p>
           <img class="logo" src="img/hombre_rie.png" alt="" width="50">
       </div>
   </div>

  <script language="javascript" src="js/evento.js" type="text/javascript">
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un array de eventos y recorrerlo para definir todos los eventos en un solo bloque. Dentro de el incluir los condicionales para definir que acción realizar:

```
var evento = document.querySelector('.navegadores');

['click', 'mouseout', 'mouseover'].forEach(evt => {
   evento.addEventListener(evt, function () {
      if (evt == 'click') {
         evento.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
         evento.style.color = 'white';
      } else if (evt == 'mouseout') {
         evento.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
         evento.style.color = 'yellow';
      } else if (evt == 'mouseover') {
         evento.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'
         evento.style.color = 'black';
      }
   });
});
```

Esta respuesta es muy similar a lo que estás tratando de resolver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845678/adding-multiple-event-listeners-to-one-element

Comment: Muy creativa la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo brindado, voy a estudiar mucho la solución de este problema y aprender cada día mas sobre esta tecnología.